# Is there a possibility to detect when my Oracle database is down without request?

Tags: c#, oracle

Is there a possibility to detect when my Oracle database is down without a request? I imagine a event from the client. Does some thing like this exist?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/ConnectionFailover.html#GUID-8B9CCE46-FA13-467D-B58E-EC940713CA3A

Answer (score 0):

My Solution I found here:
[Microsoft/ .. /dotnet/ ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-events#working-with-the-statechange-event)